# SQL Server query brings unmatched data with BETWEEN filter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, filtering, collation

I'm querying on my products table for all products with code between a range of codes, and the result brings a row that should't be there.

This is my SQL query:

```
select prdcod
from products
where prdcod between 'F-DH1' and 'F-FMS'
order by prdcod
```

and the results of this query are:

```
F-DH1
F-DH2
F-DH3
FET-RAZ       <-- What is this value doing here!?
F-FMC
F-FML
F-FMS
```

How can this odd value make it's way into the query results?

PS: I get the same results if I use `<=` and `>=` instead of `between`.

Comment: Seems like your collation excludes '-' sign - this way results make sense, FE is between FD and FM.

Comment: Thanks Arvo! You were right, and changing the collation for that column (from Modern_Spanish_CI_AS to Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) removed the odd value. Can you write this again as an answer so I can upvote you? Thanks!

Comment: @Arvo: should be an answer so we can upvote it. @Pablo: use @user which will notify "user"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*According to OP request promoted next comment to answer:*

Seems like your collation excludes '-' sign - this way results make sense, FE is between FD and FM.

*:)*

Answer (score 0):

between and >= and <= are primarily used for numeric operations (including dates). You're trying to use this for strings, which are difficult at best to determine how those operators will interpret the each string.

Now, while I think I understand your goal here, I'm not entirely sure it's possible using SQL Server queries. This may be some business logic (thanks to the product codes) that needs implemented in code. Something like the Entity Framework or Linq-to-SQL may be better suited to get you the data you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding `AND LEFT(prdcod, 2) = 'F-'`?

Comment: Can't do. These range happens to be a particular case: not all product codes begin with 'F-'. Range limits are passed by parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the "-" with a space so the order is what you would expect:

```
DECLARE @list table(word varchar(50))

--create list
INSERT INTO @list
SELECT 'F-DH1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'F-DH2'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'F-DH3'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'FET-RAZ'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'F-FMC'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'F-FML'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'F-FMS'

--original order
SELECT * FROM @list order by word

--show how order changes
SELECT *,replace(word,'-',' ') FROM @list order by replace(word,'-',' ')

--show between condition
SELECT * FROM @list where replace(word,'-',' ') between 'F DH1' and 'F FMS'
```

Comment: To do this, I'd have to know in advance all the codes in the range, which is what I'm trying to get from the query in the first place. Still, I could use "where replace(prdcod,'-',' ') between replace(@rstart,'-',' ') and replace(@rend,'-',' ')" ... but I'm looking for a solution, not a workaround.

Comment: No you wouldn't, you'd just have to replace any characters that don't give the order you'd expect. I think "-" is ignored when ordering things, but there might be other characters like that. So basically F-D is the same as FD, meaning FET-RAZ is between F-D and F-F starting codes.

Comment: Sorry, misread. You could use that in the code like you said no problem. Don't really see that as a big issue. Better than changing the collation.